# Why is Airplay from my iPhone to my Apple TV so slow?

Tags: appletv, airplay

I got the new Apple TV and noticed that it takes ages to stream a video from my iPhone.

Moreover, streaming videos directly from youtube on my iphone over airplay may cause the video to be very blurry for a few secs and then back to normal (HD), this might be due to buffering but im not sure if the internet connection has an impact on that.

Is there a way to improve the efficiency and speed of the device?

I am using a Wireless N router. The Apple TV is connected via WIFI. The iPhone is connected wireless through airplay.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, you mention streaming fro your phone (presume over Airplay), but then mention internet connection?  Can I ask you to clear up exactly what you are doing and what sorts of symptoms etc you are getting for each activity?

Comment: Are you using Wifi, aka Airport Wireless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial issue is the speed of your router. Ideally you'd have the Apple TV connected to a router via an Ethernet cable using Gigabit Ethernet (1000/baseT) and your router would have WiFi N, not Wifi G (which is slower by a factor of about five), for the iPhone connection. Then you'd want to make sure that the WiFi N router was operating on a channel not subject to interference from other routers nearby, or from physical interference that would lead to signal attenuation.

It would be a good idea to try putting your WiFi router in the same room as your Apple TV and your iPhone and to see if video image quality improves. If so, this is an indication that you were experiencing WiFi signal attenuation due to interference caused by the materials used in the walls of the building.

Also, if this is the first time you've used an AppleTV, and the first time you've tried to watch HD video streaming over the Internet on your television, it may be that your Internet connection speed from your Internet service provider simply isn't fast enough to support HD video. If you have DSL, you may wish to consider upgrading to a cable modem or fiber-optic service with higher bandwidth. This year I found that AT&T had made their Uverse fiber-optic service available in my neighborhood. I upgraded to Uverse and got Internet service at four times the speed of my old AT&T DSL service for the same price I was paying for the slower DSL.

Answer (score 1):

This worked. After 3 days of going over the same posts and no clear answer, The problem is in the appleTV software. revert to version 5.1.1 and it works great. I'm tired of people posting the same answers like we don't know any better to check the wireless router etc... any ways. reset the Apple TV and make sure it does not update to new software.
My apple TV took upto 2 min to see the Ipad screen.

Comment: I already have 5.1.1 and cannot update it further..Are you referring to another version or build of 5.1.1 ?